# Javascript blocking rest of script

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using datatables and i wanted to add the colReorder extension. The extension worked fine but it broke a lot of ajax calls i have in my js file and i can't figure out why.

The code that brakes my js

```
var colReorder = new $.fn.dataTable.ColReorder( testtable, {
    "aiOrder": [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
});

$('.reset-order-btn').click( function () {
    colReorder.fnReset();
    toastr["info"]("Columns reordered");
    return false;
} );
```

Why does this happen?

Edit: managed to narrow it down further

This brakes my js:

```
var colReorder = new $.fn.dataTable.ColReorder( testtable, {
    "aiOrder": [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
});
```

Edit 2 with clarification

So far I've found that these two functions doesn't work any more. They won't start when i click on the buttons. There might be some other things not working as I haven't tested all of them yet.

```
$('#delete-all-selections').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"/TestData/selection-delete-all/",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                    var myNode = document.getElementById("selections-list");
                    myNode.innerHTML = '';
                    toastr["error"]("All selections deleted");
                    getSelection();
            }
    })
});

$('.selection-delete-btn').click(function(){
    var selectID = this.getAttribute('data');
    console.log(selectID);
    $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"/TestData/selection-delete/"+selectID,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                    JSON = $.parseJSON(data)
                    var myNode = document.getElementById("selections-list");
                    myNode = myNode.children[JSON.selectID]
                    console.log(myNode)
                    $(myNode).remove()
                    toastr["error"]("Selection deleted");
                    getSelection();
            }
    })
});
```

And if i remove the var colReorder lines everything works as intended again.

Edit 3:
I found this error in the js console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_colReorder' of undefined
```

I've found that it tries to run this function when I load another page that has the buttons that stop working and that is why it crashes. I think I need to split my js file and load them individually on each page.

Comment: can you please create a sample on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: If you remove the 'code that breaks your other js' (include the .js include), does the other js start working?  Maybe you changed something else in the meantime?

Comment: Can you also define _in what way_ it breaks your other code?  Do you see errors in the browser console?

Comment: I'm having a hard time recreating it on js fiddle since the datatables use serverside processing and the button that no longer works is on another page.

Comment: Post a console error or something, it's hard to understand without.

Comment: Found this console error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_colReorder' of undefined`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the datatables plugin but: `var colReorder = new $.fn.dataTable.ColReorder` the `new` there doesn't look right.

Comment: Still have the same problem without the new

Comment: What's `testtable`? Because you are obviously passing something other than what it expects. Hence the "Cannot read property of undefined"

Comment: testtable is the table when it has been initialised by DataTables: `var testtable = $('#dataTables-outputTest').DataTable({` And then there's a bunch of options parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trying different stuff I finally managed to solve this problem out. I'm not exaclty sure exactly how it works but this is what i did.

I added this to my initComplete part of the table options:

```
colReorder = new $.fn.dataTable.ColReorder( testtable, {
    "aiOrder": [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
});
```

Without the var so that colReorder would become a global variable.
Then i could use this without it blocking my other functions:

```
$('.reset-order-btn').click( function () {
    colReorder.fnReset();
    toastr["info"]("Columns reordered");
    return false;
} );
```